# How can I avoid running out of RAM in a recursive call

Tags: haskell, recursion, out-of-memory

I am trying to solve Project Euler's problem 193, that consists in determining how many squarefree numbers there are below 2^50.

The algorithm that I am using is basically subtracting the numbers containing squares of primes, from all the numbers, to obtain the count of squarefree numbers.

To do so, I use inclusion and exclusion of products of squares, subtracting numbers with one square factor, adding numbers with two square factors, subtracting numbers with three square factors, etc, until I reach the maximum combination that happens to be 8 factors.

To save some work generating the combinations, I keep a list of [(product, index)], e.g.: for the product of 49 x 121 x 361, I would save (2140369,7) that tells me to start iterating from index 8 multiplying by 2140369 to obtain other combinations (of 4 numbers in this case).

The algorithm works and I can solve it with a time of 20 seconds in Python. But when I try to run my Haskell implementation, I run out of RAM, and the program does not finish.

I think it has to do with the lists `base` and `base'` being kept in memory. In python I use something like `base' = []` at the beginning of the iteration, and `base = base'.copy()` at the end, not having in memory more than this 2 lists at once.

My question is: How can I use less memory? Can I destroy lists in between recursive calls? Can I use streaming? I think the function `accum` is the one that needs to be changed.

My code is:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BLC
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Data.Vector.Unboxed ((!))
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.List (foldl')

primesSq :: Int -> [BLC.ByteString] -> [Int]
primesSq lim [] = []
primesSq pmax (b:bs) | p < pmax  = p^2 : primesSq pmax bs
                     | otherwise = primesSq pmax []
    where
        (p, _) = fromJust $ BLC.readInt b


solve :: [BLC.ByteString] -> Int -> Int
solve ls limit = total
    where
        pmax = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ limit
        ps2 = U.fromList $ primesSq pmax ls
        accumProd = U.takeWhile (< limit) $ U.scanl1 (*) ps2
        rmax = U.length accumProd
        base1 = takeWhile (\b -> fst b <= limit `div` ps2!0) 
                       (zip (U.toList ps2) [0..])
        
        accum :: [(Int,Int)] -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
        accum _ acc [] = acc
        accum base acc (r:rs) = accum base' acc' rs
            where
                base' = [(prod, j) | (p2, i) <- base
                        , j <- [i+1..U.length ps2-1]
                        , let prod = p2 * ps2 ! j 
                        , prod <= limit]
                acc' = acc + (-1)^r * sum [limit `div` p | (p,_) <- base']
        
        total = limit 
                - U.sum (U.map (div limit) ps2) 
                + accum base1 0 [2..rmax]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    ls <- BLC.lines <$> BLC.readFile "primes.txt"
    print $ solve ls (2^50)
```

Note: for this problem I didn't bother generating the prime numbers, but I read them from a text file. Besides I needed to practice reading from file.

I also tried expressing the `accum` recursion using a `scanl'`, but the result is the same, and the code is more verbose.

Comment: Well. At the very least, you have a massive space leak going on with `acc` in `accum`. `base` is also leaking, but it looks like if you fix `acc`, it'll take care of that as well.

Comment: Just to double-check: are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: @DanielWagner, Yes, I am compiling with -O2

Comment: @Carl, I think that `accum` just gets called 8 times. So `acc` would be the sum of 8 numbers only. On the other side, the lists `base` and `base'` are big, with these lengths for each call: (2 1077871 6090677), (3 6090677 6984831), (4 6984831 3952607), (5 3952607 1143807), (6 1143807 155481), (7 155481 7526), (8 7526 45)

Comment: @Carl, You mentioned leaking and fix. I am still in the beginning stages learning Haskell. I have seen things like the `!` symbol and `fix`, but I don't know if they are applicable here. Could you elaborate on your idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're gaining a lot from laziness here. You might want to try executing it with [StrictHaskell](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/strict.html?highlight=strict#bang-patterns-and-strict-haskell). That would require changing `base1`, but that shouldn't be problematic IIUC. It only goes as far as `rmax`, right?

Rather than using intermediary lists, it might be good idea to continue to leverage vector. Square root of `2ˆ50` is still a big number. Linked-list (Haskell's default list type) definitely isn't helping. Naturally, that would apply to `primesSq`, `base1`, `base'`, `acc'`.

Lastly, you might want to check out where the memory is going. This can be done with GHC's [memory profile](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/profiling.html#profiling-memory-usage) options. It would definitely help you figure out exactly where the memory is going. Moving functions to module-level (outside `where` expressions) might make visualization easier.